How would I make text bend (as if it's being folded) but not on an isometric grid?
I am trying to imitate this style of graphic (see attached photo). It's not made on an isometric grid. I think it was made using the envelope tool? But I can't quite figure it out.
Thank you!


Something similar could be created using Pathfinder and Free Transform.
Set text, and draw two rectangles over the areas you want to move/transform.

Set the fill on the rectangles to an different color (remove strokes). Select all and Pathfinder > Divide

Now delete the outer portions of the rectangles to reveal the type shapes. You'll need to delete the filled in counters as well (the center of the O, the holes in the B and R, the inner corner of the hole in the A, etc.)

Now use the Direct Selection Tool (White arrow) to click-drag and select all the anchors except the one closest to the center shapes. Note the anchor selection in the image below. The anchors closest to black are not selected, therefore they won't move when the other anchors are transformed.

Grab the Free Transform Tool and skew and distort things...

Repeat for other side....

Change colors, select all and perspective distort...

Took much, much longer to type this than to actually do this.
You can make the rectangles more trapezoidal, so that the "folds" are at more of an angle. That will merely entail more careful anchor point selection before using Free Transform. I used straight rectangles to make anchor selection easier to explain.

I would use a 3D Extrusion for this. Here's a brief outline of the process

Type some text, light grey fill

Draw a path, and stroke it grey

Add a 3D extrusion to it, and use the text as a material, set the rendering to vector

Use the invisible geometry option. Move the perspective slider to get the effect you want. And then add a black rectangle as the background.

Draw some rectangles filled dark grey for shading, and set their blend mode to multiply


Click to see larger
Here's the finished result


You can convert the text to outlines, split it and then recolor and shear the areas. Shearing doesn't spoil the proportions in the seam if it happens vertically and the splitting seam is also vertical. An example:

The text is rotated 30 degrees, an exactly  vertical red line is drawn over it and the text is outlined. That's why the anchor points are visible.
The line is selected and Object > Path > Divide Objects Below is applied. Because the division line was vertical it's easy to select the halves and give new fill colors

The halves are also both grouped to keep their parts together easily. In the next image the left half is sheared vertically. Holding shift limits the movement direction:

The sheared part can be moved to snap and fit exactly:

Select all, rotate to a new angle, draw a new vertical line, divide, colorize and shear and move the parts again together:

This site wants that the source of the used material is clearly mentioned. The used text is taken from this distinguished concert performance of classical music https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGksgZKecKE
